# Convert UCS 2 to UTF8 via BATCH

Tags: php, batch-file, utf-8, cmd, utf

I would like to convert a CSV File from UCS2 to UTF8 via Batch. I've tried

```
iconv --from-code UCS-2 - UTF-8 -c export_RV-RP.csv > export_RV-RP2.csv
```

But it didn't work, the file is empty.

Can anyone tell me the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the syntax wrong and there's a single dash in your command. Try this:

```
iconv -f UCS-2 -t UTF-8 -c export_RV-RP.csv > export_RV-RP2.csv
```

Comment: Its still an empty file.